# CSS for a custom shape and adding image below that shape

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Thanks for the help in advance. I was trying code the design of the below image. For that i used the before and after to create the shape.But when i tried to place the dot pattern image as in the design i got stuck.I tried z-index but was not successful.Can anyone help me to resolve this issue
[image]

The code i wrote

```css
.banner {
  padding-top: 8rem;
  position: relative;
  height: 75rem;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #03062f 0%, #180b74 100%);
}
.banner::before, .banner::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}
.banner::before {
  background: #f1f5f9;
  height: 18rem;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: skewY(4.2deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  bottom: -19rem;
}
.banner::after {
  width: 16rem;
  height: 16rem;
  border-bottom: solid 8rem #f1f5f9;
  border-right: solid 8rem #f1f5f9;
  border-left: solid 80px transparent;
  border-top: solid 8rem transparent;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -4rem;
  background: #150a6b;
}

.dot-pattern {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 14rem;
  bottom: -7.5rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
      <div class="container h-100 position-relative">
        <div class="dot-pattern">
          <img src="assets/img/svg/dots.svg" alt="dots" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [polygon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape/polygon) to handle the bottom edges

The grey rectangle below represents the dots

If you want to do some tests with `polygon` you can use this website https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

The result will be something like this
[image]

If it solves your issue, don't forget to mark the correct answer. Thanks

```css
:root {
  --width: 800px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  background-color: darkblue;
  width: var(--width);
  height: 300px;
}
.nested-box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
.triangle {
  width: var(--width);
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #dd4f39;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 103% 0, 96% 100%);
}

.box2 {
  background-color: grey;
  width: var(--width);
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: -16px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="nested-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="triangle"></div>
      <div class="box2"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the issue might be related to the stacking context created by the transform property in your ::before pseudo-element. When you apply a transform property to an element, it creates a stacking context, affecting the rendering order of elements.

To ensure that the dot pattern is displayed on top of the skewed shape, you should adjust the stacking context and set a higher z-index for the .dot-pattern element. Here's a modified version of your CSS:

```css
.banner {
  padding-top: 8rem;
  position: relative;
  height: 75rem;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #03062f 0%, #180b74 100%);
}

.banner::before,
.banner::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  z-index: 1; /* Ensure that the pseudo-elements are behind the dot pattern */
}

.banner::before {
  background: #f1f5f9;
  height: 18rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: skewY(4.2deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  bottom: -19rem;
}

.banner::after {
  width: 16rem;
  height: 16rem;
  border-bottom: solid 8rem #f1f5f9;
  border-right: solid 8rem #f1f5f9;
  border-left: solid 80px transparent;
  border-top: solid 8rem transparent;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -4rem;
  background: #150a6b;
}

.dot-pattern {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2; /* Ensure that the dot pattern is above the pseudo-elements */
  height: 14rem;
  bottom: -7.5rem;
}
```

By setting a higher z-index for the .dot-pattern element, you should ensure that it appears on top of the pseudo-elements in the stacking order. Adjust the z-index values as needed to achieve the desired visual hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of `linear-gradient`, `conic-gradient`, `radial-gradient` you can get essentially any color pattern you want. A gradient need not be a gradient. Some gradients result in solid color fields. And you can control placement with `background-position`, size with `background-size`, and just do single fields of color with a `no-repeat`.

For your image, the trickiest bit is the repeating dot pattern. In my solution I use white to "cover" the dots. I use fields of white to create the same resulting shape. I could also have done a `repeat-y` for each of the 13 columns of dots, but I would still have to cover some of those dots with white. In which case the way to do the discontinuous dots is to place each one with a new `radial-gradient`. Or, I could have done a separate HTML element for the dots and then used a `clip-path` to get the cut out shape. Come to think of it, the main blue block could *also* be done using a clip-path.

The solution I have come up with uses 7 CSS gradients to reproduce the image, specifically to match the source image. I've further set the width of the `section.banner` to match that image for simplicity's sake.

CSS gradients like this are very sensitive to hacking. It can be very frustrating to edit increasingly complicated gradient CSS because one bad value, misplaced comma, putting `px` when you meant `deg` will cause the whole stack of blocks to collapse. Also, each of the values for size, repeat, position, and image must have a corresponding value. As you add and experiment you need to add entries for each associated gradient.

Also note the solution below is in pixels because I wanted to match precisely. It is usually possible (but requires testing) to use percentage values for many of the px values in this, which if all done correctly could result in this being a background that could scale to whatever size the element is, and if the size is controlled with `aspect-ratio: 1440 / 810` all the gradients should scale proportionally.

But usually, the task at hand is just to get the image done. I could just have easily redone the image in a vector based editor and output a small `svg` to represent the whole image. Using complex gradients is great but not always the best way to get the job done.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
section.banner {
  height:  810px;
    width: 1440px;
  background-image:
    /* 1 for middle top flat blue block */
    linear-gradient(
      #0e0954,
      #0e0954
    ),
    /* 1 dark shade blue translucent top to bottom */
    linear-gradient(
      #030630,
      transparent 
    ),
    /* 1 angular background facing upward */
    conic-gradient(
      from 57deg at 1331px 750px,
      transparent 219deg,
      #170b71 219deg
    ),
    /* 3 white to cover repeatting dot pattern */
    linear-gradient(
      transparent 810px,
      #fff 0
    ),
    conic-gradient(
      from 90deg at 360px 740px,
      #fff 90deg,
      transparent 0
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      #fff 180px,
      transparent 180px 415px,
      #fff 415px),
    /* 1 for dot pattern */
    radial-gradient(
      circle at 6px 6px, 
      #e8edf3 6px, 
      transparent 0)
    ;
  background-size: 
    1202px 612px,
    1440px 612px,
    1440px 810px,
    1440px 810px,
    1440px 810px, 
    1440px 810px,
    20px 24px;
  background-repeat: 
    no-repeat,
    no-repeat,
    no-repeat,
    no-repeat,
    no-repeat,
    no-repeat,
    repeat;
  background-position: 
    136px 0,
    0 0,
    0 0,
    0 0, 
    0 0, 
    0 0,
    0 5px;

}
```

```html
<section class="banner"></section>
```